# Jquery Data table is showing message No matching records found

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I want to bind json data received to the jquery data table.I have following questions as follows.
1. Is my HTML code correct?
2. Json data received is in correct format?
3. Am I using right script to render jquery data table please help.

I am attaching code as well as screen shot of data received.

```
public JsonResult This_is_final(int FirstNameCount, int LastNameCount, int TotalSalary, int GenderCount)
        {
            List<Counting> l = new List<Counting>();
            l.Add(new Counting() { FirstNamecount = FirstNameCount, LastNamecount = LastNameCount, Salary = TotalSalary, Gendercount = GenderCount });
            //System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            //string aaData = jSearializer.Serialize(l);
            //Console.WriteLine(FirstNameCount + "" + LastNameCount + "" + TotalSalary + "" + GenderCount);
            // aaData = "{\"data\": " + aaData + "}";
            var todoListsResults = l.Select(
                 a => new
                 {

                     a.FirstNamecount,
                     a.LastNamecount,
                     a.Salary,
                     a.Gendercount

                 });

            var jsonData = new
            {
               iTotalRecords= "54",
               iTotalDisplayRecords="22",
               aadata = todoListsResults
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }


Jquery script:-
```

---

```
function callme(fncount, lncount, i, gndr) { 


        $('#example').dataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url: "/TodoList/This_is_final",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'FirstNameCount': fncount, 'LastNameCount': lncount, 'TotalSalary': i, 'GenderCount': gndr
                },
                dataSrc: function (json) {

                    alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                    return { "data":json };
                }
            },
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "searching": true,
            "columns": [
                 { "mdata": "FirstNamecount" },
                 { "mdata": "LastNamecount" },
                 { "mdata": "TotalSalary" },
                 { "mdata": "GenderCount" }
            ]
        });

}
```

[image]

Comment: hi @Baji do you already have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using datatable for data binding but i am using JQuery post function to get JsonResult data as

```
$.post("../TodoList/This_is_final", { "FirstNameCount": fncount, "LastNameCount": lncount},
    function (data) { if (data != null) {
           var table = $("#example").dataTable({
                        "iDisplayLength": 10,
                        "aaData": data,
                        "aoColumns": [
                                  { "sTitle": "First Name", "sWidth": "20%"},
                                  { "sTitle": "Last Name", "sWidth": "20%"}]
})} }
```

In view

```
public JsonResult This_is_final(int FirstNameCount, int LastNameCount)
    {
        List<Counting> l = new List<Counting>();
        l.Add(new Counting() { FirstNamecount = FirstNameCount, LastNamecount = LastNameCount });
          var todoListsResults = l.Select(
             a => new[]
             {

                 a.FirstNamecount,
                 a.LastNamecount,                     
             }).ToArray();

       return Json(todoListsResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Updated your code..